# chrome extension: page loaded event and update url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to change the url of current tab in chrome and reload the page.
I tried this code but not work, any help here will be greatly appreciated.

background.js:

```
function updateUrl(){

    chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function (tab) {

        var tabUrl = encodeURIComponent(tab.url);

        var myNewUrl = tabUrl + "some text";

        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: myNewUrl});
   })
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {

        updateUrl();

    }
})
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation",
    "http://www.example.com/*"
  ],

  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },

  "content_scripts":
  [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.example.com/*"], 
      "js":  ["background.js", "jquery.js"]
    }
  ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your manifest it looks like you're trying to include background.js as a content script and a background script. `chrome.tabs` isn't available in content scripts so this won't work.

Depending on your specific use case, if you want to append a specific URL you could use the [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API to achieve this.

background.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {
    return {
        redirectUrl: details.url + "some text"
    }
}, {
    urls: ["http://www.example.com/*"]
}, ["blocking"]);
```

manifest.js:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "http://www.example.com/*"
  ],
  "background": { 
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ] 
  }
}
```

This will add "some text" to the end of every request the browser makes to "http://www.example.com/*"

If you do want to use a content script to do this, then you'll need to take a look at [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). This will allow you to make a call to the background script (which can use `chrome.tabs`) from your content script. Once the message has been sent the background page could then update the tab.

Answer (score 0):

1. [`chrome.tabs.getCurrent`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getCurrent) is used to get the tab that this script is being made from. It will return `undefined` if called from a non-tab context (for example: a **background page** or popup view).

   Since you have got the tab inside `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` handler, you could directly use it without the need to retrieve it again.

   ```
   function updateUrl(tabId, tabUrl){
       var myNewUrl = encodeURIComponent(tabUrl) + "some text";
       chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {url: myNewUrl});
   }

   chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
       if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
           updateUrl(tab.id, tab.url);
       }
   });
   ```
2. From you `manifest.json`, `background.js` are used for both background page and content scripts, that's a **bad design** though not the root cause for this question.

   It would be better if you could divide the logic into two parts, content script used for manipulating current web page DOM and background page used for extension related things.